# 'The RPC server is unavailable' when converting a physical ISA/Forefront TMG machine to virtual (P2V) in SCVMM

Tags: wmi, isa-server, rpc, physical-to-virtual, tmg

When I try to convert a physical ISA/TMG machine to virtual using SCVMM, i keep getting an error in the Collect machine configuration step ('Scan Now' button):

> VMM is unable to complete the request. The connection to the agent MACHINE_NAME
>   was lost.
>
> Ensure that the computer MACHINE_NAME exists on the network, WMI service and
>   the agent are installed and running and that a firewall is not
>   blocking HTTP and WMI traffic.
>
> ID: 3157 Details: The RPC server is unavailable (0x800706BA)

Firewall rules allow for RPC traffic from the SCVMM machine to ISA/TMG machine.

Answer (score 1):

**Cause:** the ISA/TMG server is still blocking specific RPC/WMI traffic, which is not visible when logging the incoming traffic on the server

**Resolution:**

1. Make sure that you have an appropriate Firewall Policy rule that will allow for RPC traffic from SCVMM to TMG server
2. Right-click on the said rule, click "Configure RPC protocol"
3. Uncheck "Enforce strict RPC compliance"
4. From the right-side menu, click Tasks, then Edit System Policy
5. Under "Remote Management" group, select "Microsoft Management Console (MMC)"
6. Uncheck "Enable this configuration group"

The physical-to-virtual process for an ISA/TMG machine will now resume normally.
Undo the changes on the virtual TMG machine after the P2V process is complete.

Comment: On Windows 10, how do I get to "Configure RPC Protocol" - what tool do I open?